# Adding new rows to the grid

Tags: ag-grid

I initialise ag-grid like:

`<ag-grid-ng2 [rowData]="records"></ag-grid-ng2>`

After adding new items to the records array, rows in ag-grid are remain not updeted.
I have to call setRowData(records). But this is very slow and ag-grid loses its state (like focused cell).

Is there another way to have rows in ag-grid refreshed during changing data in `rowData`.

Answer (score 5):

no, there is no other way. the grid expects rowData to be immutable, which means you have to replace the array for the [rowData] property to be picked up. the way around this, as you do, is to call the api.setRowData() method, which forces the grid to treat the rowData as a new set of data.

Comment: To add new columns, it is indeed necessary to use the setRowData() method after the new rows have been added. I put a link to the official documentation:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-row-data/

Answer (score 1):

Recently I noticed a new function `this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData(Tranactions)`. You pass an object with three arrays:

```
var transactions = {
    add: [/*array of records you want to add.*/]
    remove: [/*array of records you want to remove.*/]
    update: [/*array of records you want to update.*/]
}

this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData(tranactions);
```

Reference: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/?framework=javascript. (For some reason on that page they call the function *updateData* but no such function exists. Rather it's called `updateRowData`.)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. May be I lose some functionality and will have some bugs, but for me it works now.

```
AddRecord(data) {
    this.records.push(data);
    var id = this.records.length-1;
    var node = {childIndex:id, data: this.records[id], firstChild: false, id:id, lastChild: false};
    this.gridOptions.api.grid.inMemoryRowController.rowsAfterMap.push(node);
    this.gridOptions.api.rowRenderer.refreshView(id);
    this.gridOptions.api.hideOverlay();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up adding new records.
You can use the `applyTransaction()` function for this (I think this use to be known as `updateRowData()`).

```
var newItems = [createNewRowData(), createNewRowData(), createNewRowData()];
var res = this.gridApi.applyTransaction({
  add: newItems,
  addIndex: addIndex,
});
```

The above code is from [their example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update-transactions/).